# GTA Online job and heist stuck loading issue

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

On the PC, I have a problem when I'm starting a job (Lester) or heist. In the case of heists, it is stuck with the green filter, and for the jobs, it is stuck at the top-down perspective and loading for eternity (and it doesn't load). Tried restarting, and cleaning the cache in Launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of overloaded servers due to that epic games offer, there are a few methods that you can try :-

Method 1) Try switching to character select, then wait for some time
    then open it again.

Method 2) Open Task Manager and suspend gtav.exe, wait for some time
        to empty the server and un-suspend it again.

Method 3) Try opening the heist from invites.

I tried above methods and works most of times for me.